# How Can I change the Gridview Fast Scrollbar style?

Tags: gridview, scrollbar, fastscroll

How can I change the Fast scrollbar style in gridview in android. When I scroll the gridview images then fast scroll is displaying but the textview displaying very big size. So I want to set custom style in place of default.

Comment: I also facing this issue in android scroll bar style..

Comment: I change the fast scrollbar textview in some better but not exatly I want by this line android:scrollbarTrackVertical=""